# FAT32 128GB Sandisk flash drive isn't working after deleting System Volume Information

Tags: usb-flash-drive, filesystem-corruption

after trying to delete files on my flash drive I accidentally deleted System Volume Information thinking it was useless. I know Windows has restore points to restore the folder but after that my flash drive straight up just won't work. Maybe it isn't that folder but I've looked at the connected devices and saw that my computer at the least recognizes it. However it does not recognize it as a flash drive only some piece of external hardware. I have got it to show up as a drive with 0 bytes of storage capacity but that's no good. I've followed many guides about diskpart and downloading fancy applications that "claim" to fix your flashdrive and they ended up being a disappointment. If anybody can help me that would be great.

Comment: If the filesystem was damaged then Windows would offer to reformat it. The hardware itself is gone.

Answer (score 0):

For a USB flash drive, the System Volume Information folder is not mission-critical. Proof: Format a USB flash drive in Linux (with FAT32, ExFAT or NTFS) and then plug it to a Windows computer. It still works. Windows just creates a System Volume Information folder on it.

I believe you are mistaking two things that coincidentally happened at the same times as being cause and effects. They are not.

From your description, it appears your USB flash drive is dead. (Because this is how USB flash drives die.) If your warranty period has not expired, take it to a service center. Otherwise, there is not much you can do. For the future, consider carrying it in a shockproof anti-static box. I've been told that this is overkill and does not improve their lifespan, but then again, none of my USB flash drives (some of which are more than one decade old) have died yet.